# sbt-idea & sub-projects

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-idea

If, say, your sbt project contained 50 sub projects. Is it possible to generate an intellij project where you specify a set of the sub projects comes from your repo and for the other set of sub projects are actually contained in the project file ?

i.e. i'm looking to work on only a small subset of sub projects at a time and I know I won't need to change / compile the the other sub projects.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can define the following layout in `project/Build.scala` where you combine projects you're working on in `meta` project:

```
object MyBuild extends Build {

  lazy val meta = Project(
    id = "meta",
    base = file(".")) aggregate(A,B) dependsOn(A,B)

  lazy val A = Project(id = "A",base = file("A"))) 

  lazy val B = Project(id = "B",base = file("B")))

  ... }
```

Then type `project meta` at sbt startup (if it is not meta already) and then `gen-idea`.

But every time you need to change projects set you're working on, you need to change meta definition and issue `gen-idea`.

Comment: That seems good, but notice that the projects not included in the workset must be specified as local jar dependencies.